# Split Mysql output to several pages

Tags: php, mysql, split

I wanted to ask in general how it is possible to split a MySQL output on several PHP pages.

For example, I want to retrieve different user entries such as blog entries, but only display e.g. 5 entries per page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/mysql-limit-offset

Read also about pagination https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html